# Fastest rate of convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

For the fastest rate of convergence of the method $x_{n-1}=\frac{ax_n -x_n^2+1}{a+x_n}$, the value of $a$ is (given $\alpha$ is an exact root)

$1. \frac{1}{\alpha^2}$

$2. \frac{1}{\alpha^3}$

$3. \frac{2}{\alpha^3}$

$4. \frac{3}{\alpha^2}$

I tried putting $\lim_\limits{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{|x_n-\alpha|}{|x_{n-1}-\alpha|}=m$, $0<m<1$, but reached nowhere. Any hints, Thanks!

Comment: Is that supposed to be $x_{n+1}$ on the left side of the equation?

Comment: please check your formula. usually the indexes of the righ are larger than the indexes on the left. If you assume that $\lim x_n =\alpha$ and take the $\lim$ on both sides it follows that $\alpha$ must be $0$.

Comment: I misead your formula. $\lim$ would result in $\alpha=\frac 1 {\sqrt2}$

Comment: Though it is $x_{n-1}$ on LHS but still want to see what is the way to do it with $x_{n+1}$?

Comment: if it is $x_{n-1}$ does not make sensethen transform it in an equation of the type $x_n=f(x_{n-1}$).

Answer (score 0):

The equation is equivalent to
$$
x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{2x_n^2-1}{a+x_n}\tag1
$$
Thus, the only stationary points are $x=\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}$.  If we set $a=\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}-a
&=x_n-a-\frac{2x_n^2-2a^2}{a+x_n}\tag2\\
&=x_n-a-2(x_n-a)\tag3\\[6pt]
&=-\left(x_n-a\right)\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: subtract $a$ from both sides of $(1)$ and use $a=\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}$
$(3)$: simplify the fraction $\vphantom{\frac1{\sqrt2}}$
$(4)$: subtract

Iteration $(4)$ does not give convergence at all, but oscillation around the stationary point.

Comment: @robjohn...please elaborate how you got $x_{n+1}-a=-(x_n-a)$ ?

Comment: That's correct, but not an answer: $a=\alpha$ was not among the choices 1.-4. Obviously, $a=3\alpha$ would be optimal, option 1 is closest (starting from $1$, 6 digits  accuracy after 5 iterations)..

Comment: Professor Vector...how did you get $a=3\alpha$?

Comment: @toddler: plug $a=\pm\frac1{\sqrt2}$ into my first equation, subtract $a$ from both sides, and simplify.